# How to stop character substitutions (like ... to ellipsis) in UWP TextBox

Tags: uwp, textbox

Short of sniffing characters and manually making replacements, how do I stop a multiline [UWP TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox#properties) from replacing three periods/dots (...) with a Unicode ellipsis character (…)?

I've tried turning off [`IsTextPrediction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.istextpredictionenabled#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_IsTextPredictionEnabled), but that didn't do it. I'm not sure any other properties look promising.

I also get substitutions like capital `I` for `i` by itself on a line, or `NPM` auto-capitalized when I type `npm` (but not always!).

---

For what it's worth, this *wasn't* how the `TextBox` originally behaved. Originally, no substitutions happen. Then I believe for a while I was getting not only ellipses but smart quotes (“”) for plain quotes (") as well, though the smart quote substitution seems to have stopped.

Also fun: The three periods substitution with ellipses isn't consistent. I typed the following without any backspaces or edits:

[image: seemingly random ellipses substitution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/text-controls#guidelines-for-spell-checking), TextBox contains spell checking function, and it controled by [`IsSpellCheckEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isspellcheckenabledproperty#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_IsSpellCheckEnabledProperty) property, please set it as false.

> The spell checking engine automatically corrects misspelled words when it's confident about the correction. For example, the engine automatically changes "teh" to "the."

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

**Update**

For disable autocorrect misspelled words, you could open system setting and found Typing setting page and switch off Autocorrect misspelled words.

Comment: So I _do_ want spell check; I just don't want autocorrect -- and if that means I have to have `npm` become `NPM`, fine. It's the extended characters that are inescapably invasive. I'll check the doc you linked this evening and see if that's covered. But this is the only way I can avoid the high character substitutions, then I suppose I'll have to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, if you have any updates please feel free post here.

Comment: Ah, that's it exactly! The context is that I have a Markdown editor, and I want people to be able to enter in "low byte" text easily, producing docs that aren't _quite_ like a word processor's, but perhaps continue to have misspellings in their text highlighted. I still don't understand why some `...`s are autocorrected and some aren't, and I wish I could set that Typing setting _within the scope of my app only_ (I'll update if I ever figure that out), but your answer gives me great options for helping the user get to their preferred outcome. Thanks!